# уведомления в определенный момент времени

Tags: java, service, broadcast-receiver, android-notification

Нужно реализовать показ уведомлений по времени, допустим каждый час, как я понимаю нужен broadcast receiver, из него нужно запускать IntentService и там стартовать рукурсивную функцию для проверки времени, типа:

```
void checkTime(){
if(min == 45){
  notification
}else{
     checkTime()
     }
}
```

но вот проблема в том, что если я создаю уведомление в broadcast, все ок, а если делаю из него startService, то он не стартует

Comment: Проверьте добавлен ли сервис в манифест.

Comment: Вот я....грррр...
забыл добавить)))

Comment: Написал в ответе. Если проблема была в этом - отметьте ответ верным и проголосуйте за него
)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Скорее всего проблема в отсутствии объявления сервиса в манифесте.